# How to reduce the number of for-loops for shortening running time in Python programming?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on Python programming. 
The problem is that my code is too slow to get the data in few days.

My code is as below. And dic dictionary data is like this; dic[0] = ['happy', 100, [1234, 1245, 1515, 1785, ... up to 100]] That is, dic[0][1] represents the length of the dic[0][2]. What I want to do is to calculate DICE Coefficient (word similarity) (dic[i][0] represents a word (in the example above, 'happy'), dic[i][1] represent the length of dic[i][2] (just len(dic[i][2])), dic[i][2] represents the list of line numbers where that word (dic[i][0]) appears. Here line means just the line number in corpus)

DICE Coefficient is calculated in this way : number of appearance of two words (word1, word2) together in a sentence / (number of total appearance of word1 + number of total appearance of word2).

The total data is (so) big. My program has worked for 2 days.. but no result yet.. I have to use the result as soon as possible because this work's deadline is next week..

Is there any alternative (much better) algorithm that I can implement right away? 
Thanks.

```
for j in range(len(dic)):
            for k in range(len(dic)):

                score_temp = 0

                for r in range(len(dic[j][2])):
                    if(dic[j][2][r] in dic[k][2]):
                        score_temp += 1
                score_final = float(score_temp) / (dic[j][1] + dic[k][1])
                dice_cursor.execute('insert into dices values(?,?,?)', (dic[j][0], dic[k][0], score_final))
```

Comment: Please, at least explain the real problem. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary I changed my post. Sorry for short explanation.

Comment: Is `dic` actually a `dict` whose keys are the sequential natural numbers from 0 through `len(dic)`? If so, why aren't you just using a `list`?

Comment: OK, now that you posted more information… `dic` actually _is_ a list, not a dict. And I don't know why you're storing `len(dic[j][2])` in `dic[j][1]`, because you can already get `len` immediately.

Comment: @abarnert I think it is just my misunderstanding.. But, is that make my code slow?

Comment: @abarnert Right Right. Here, for r in range(len(dic[j][2])): , I can use dic[j][1] instead of len(dic[j][2]). But I think this makes not that big difference in running time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't really your algorithm; it's your data structure.

If I understand your problem, you have to iterate over all `j, k` combinations; there's simply no way around that. So the best algorithm possible will be quadratic on the length of `dic`.

However, for each pair, you're repeatedly doing a bunch of linear searches, for `dic[j][2][r] in dic[k][2]`. And *that* part is unnecessary. If you just change every one of those `dic[*][2]` lists into sets, the same lookups become instantaneous.

So, instead of `O(N^2 * M^2)`, where `N` is the length of `dic` and `M` is the (average?) length of `dic[*][2]`, it'll be `O(N^2 * M)`. Still slow, but much faster.

You haven't shown us where you build this giant list, so I can't show you how to build it differently… but usually it's just a matter of starting with `set()` and calling `.add` instead of starting with `[]` and calling `.append`.

Or, if you can't change the way it's built, you can always change it after the fact:

```
dic = [[a, b, set(c)] for a, b, c in dic]
```

---

I'm assuming here you're not counting duplicates twice. If you're supposed to, I think you're doing it wrong—you're counting duplicates in the `j` but not in the `k`. But anyway, you can solve that by using a "multiset" type; usually `collections.Counter` is the simplest way to do that.

---

You can also make it simpler (although only a little faster), by using set intersection instead of iterating over one set to check the other. Instead of this:

```
for r in range(len(dic[j][2])):
    if(dic[j][2][r] in dic[k][2]):
        temp_score += 1
```

… do this:

```
temp_score += len(dic[j][2] & dic[k][2])
```

---

And while we're at it, instead of doing `for j in range(len(dic))` and then using `dic[j]` all over the place, you can just use `for x in dic` and use `x`. Like this:

```
for x in dic:
    for y in dic:
        score_temp = len(x[2] & y[2])
        score_final = float(score_temp) / (x[1] + y[1])
        dice_cursor.execute('insert into dices values(?,?,?)', 
                            (x[0], y[0], score_final))
```

Or, even more concisely:

```
for x, y in itertools.product(dic, dic):
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think your explanation will be very helpful. Now, I will halt my running program and just implement what you explained. Thanks again. : )

Comment: Ah.. Can I ask one more question? The len(dic) is just about 770. But the average len of dic[i][2] is about 100,000 or more.. So, your way will be more helpful?

Comment: @GoodGJ: Definitely! That means you go from 770*770*100000*100000 steps to 770*770*100000, which is 100000 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many problems with your code:

Since you're using `range()` to iterate over the keys of your dict, starting from 0, it seems, you would be better off just using a list, which is, in essence, just a mapping from integers to values, where the integers are consecutive and start at 0. Also, the keys seem to play no other role in your code but to address the entries in your dict. That means, you don't have to iterate over `range()` at all. Instead, you should iterate like so (assuming you use a list and not a dict):

```
for a in the_list:
    for b in the_list:
        ...
        for value in a[2]:
            if value in b[2]:
                ...
```

Still, this is only slightly better. It would be much better if you could use sets instead of lists as third entry in your data. The `in` operator on lists has a time complexity of O(n). On sets it has only O(1) on average. Also, you could use the proper function from the standard library. Then you arrive at something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

the_list = [
    ['happy', 100, set([<100 elements>)]],
    ['unhappy', 90, set([<90 elements>)]],
    ['green', 120, set([<120 elements>)]],
    ['red', 50, set([<50 elements>)]],
    ...
]

for a, b in combinations(the_list, 2):

    score = len(a[2] & b[2])
    dice_cursor.execute('insert into dices values(?,?,?)', (a[0], b[0], score))
    dice_cursor.execute('insert into dices values(?,?,?)', (b[0], a[0], score))

# now the pairings we didn't generate so far:
for a in the_list:
    dice_cursor.execute('insert into dices values(?,?,?)', (a[0], a[0], len(a[2])))
```